# how to compare my password "bcrypt" with my database?

Tags: java, sql, spring

For the authentication of my application, I have a control of my password "hashed" of the form and that of my database which is also "hashé", but that does not work?

Here is my condition :

```
BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
if ((pseudobdd.equals(loginForm.get("pseudo").toString()))
                        && 
(encoder.matches(passwordbdd, loginForm.get("password").toString()))) {
```

"passwordbdd" and "loginForm.get("password").toString()" are "hashed" in the same way...

Comment: Why the <sql> tag? I see no SQL there.

Answer (score 0):

> "passwordbdd" and "loginForm.get("password").toString()" are "hashed" in the same way...

The password you get from the form shouldn't be hashed. This is the way the BCryptPasswordEncoder mathes method works:

```
    if(encoder.matches(userInputPassword, databaseHashedPassword)) {
        // intput password matches! 
    }
```

Comment: I removed the password hash from the form, but it still does not work?

Comment: and i have in the console : Encoded password does not look like BCrypt

Comment: it works by replacing BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder(); by PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();